# Size of arithmetic operation result in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am making a signed comparator in Verilog. Here is the code:

```
module signedComparator(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, G, E, L);
input a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;
output reg G, E, L;

always@(a0 or a1 or a2 or b0 or b1 or b2)
begin

    if(a2 == 0 && b2 == 0) //both a and b >= 0
    begin
        L <= {a1,a0} < {b1,b0};
        G <= {a1,a0} > {b1,b0};
        E <= {a1,a0} == {b1,b0}; 
    end
    else if(a2 == 1 && b2 == 0) //a negative, b >= 0
    begin
        L <= 1;
        G <= 0;
        E <= 0;
    end
    else if(a2 == 0 && b2 == 1) //a >= 0, b negative
    begin
        L <= 0;
        G <= 1;
        E <= 0;
    end
    else //both a and b negative
    begin
        L <= (~{a1,a0} + 1) > (~{b1,b0} + 1);
        G <= (~{a1,a0} + 1) < (~{b1,b0} + 1);
        E <= (~{a1,a0} + 1) == (~{b1,b0} + 1);
    end

end
endmodule
```

I am wondering, when adding vectors, what is the length of the intermediate result? I am concerned about the last case (`L <= (~{a1,a0} + 1) > (~{b1,b0} + 1);`). When adding 1 to ~{a1,a0}, is the result three bits in length for the comparison, or will {1,1} + 1 = {0,0}? Is there documentation somewhere for what the data type of intermediate results in verilog will be? This is hard to search for since I don't yet know the proper terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming this is for synthesis and have a few comments about your code. You seem to be using individual bits as inputs to the module and then using concatenation to make vectors later on. You can avoid this by declaring ports as signed vectors and doing a comparison directly.

```
input signed [2:0] a,b;
...
if(a == b)
...
else if(a > b)
...
else
...
```

Also, you are using non-blocking assignments to model combinational logic. These will work in the code you posted but really shouldn't be used in this manner. They work much better modeling synchronous logic via a clocked process. There's a [good paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) that summarizes a good coding style for synthesis.

> I am wondering, when adding vectors, what is the length of the intermediate result?

The spec has a table for this as it depends on the operands and context.

- An integer : Unsized constants are at least 32-bits
- {a,b}      : sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)
- ~{a}       : sizeof(a)
- a + b      : max(sizeof(a),sizeof(b))

Thus your comparison operands will both be (at least) 32-bits. You can explicitly assign a constant size by using a tick before the value.

```
4'b1 // 0001 Binary 1
4'd1 // 0001 Decimal 1
4'd8 // 1000 Decimal 8
1'b1 //    1 Binary 1
'b1  // The same as 1, tick here only specifies dec/oct/bin format
```

> Is there documentation somewhere for what the data type of
>   intermediate results in verilog will be?

By far the best resource I've found for details like this is the spec itself, IEEE 1364.

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I was I looking for and more. This is for a logic design class, so I don't think declaring a and b as signed vectors would fly (need to show I understand how two's complement works), but that is good to know for future assignments. Interesting paper, which probably saved my future self from some painful debugging. Thanks!

Comment: The width of `a + b` is actually context dependent.  If it is assigned to an expression 1 bit wider than `max(sizeof(b),sizeof(b))`, the expression will be evaluated at the wider size.  IEEE 1364 lists this example explicitly, but does not seem to describe the context rules as rigorously as the self-determined case.

Comment: I've always been surprised it depends on the operands and not the size of the receiver.